# Custom outlook plug in not downloading as expected

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

I have written a custom code such that when ever an email arrives which has an attachment,it must get downloaded into a shared location, and email arrives daily.

When I open my laptop daily it's working fine if i don't open and if there are continuous mails (with attachments) and it is not getting downloaded for example, when i open my laptop on monday I have 3 mails with attachment  (from satu, sunday,  monday).

It is not downloading the latest report from monday it is still showing me same report on saturday.

Here is my code..

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender,System.EventArgs e) {
    outlookNameSpace=this.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    inbox=outlookNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
    items=inbox.Items;
    items.ItemAdd +=new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(items_ItemAdd);
}
private void items_ItemAdd(object Item) {
    Outlook.Items inboxitems;
    const string destinationDirectory=@"\\Service Now\";
    Outlook.MailItem newEmail=null;
    inboxitems=inbox.Items.Restrict("[Unread] = true");
    try {
        foreach (object collectionItem in inboxitems) {
            newEmail=collectionItem as Outlook.MailItem;
            if (newEmail !=null) {
                if (newEmail.Attachments.Count > 0) {
                    for (int i=1; i <= newEmail.Attachments.Count; i++) {
                        if (newEmail.Attachments[i].FileName.Contains("Logic")) {
                            //   String Des= destinationDirectory.Remove(0, 1);
                            newEmail.Attachments[i].SaveAsFile(destinationDirectory + newEmail.Attachments[i].FileName);
                            //  MessageBox.Show("Hurry");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }catch (System.Exception ex) {
        MessageBox.Show(""+ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to debug the code?

I see the following conditions in the code:

```
inboxitems= inbox.Items.Restrict("[Unread] = true");
```

and

```
if (newEmail.Attachments[i].FileName.Contains( "Logic"))
```

Make sure that emails corresponds to the conditions shown above.

Be aware, the ItemAdd event of the Items class *is not* fired when a large number of items are added to the folder at once (more than 16).

P.S. Try to check out the [MarkForDownload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866920(v=office.15).aspx) property of Outlook items - an [OlRemoteStatus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862994.aspx) value that determines the status of an item once it is received by a remote user.

Comment: Debugging working fine, problem is only when I open my laptop on monday only 3 mails are there (from Saturday,Sun and MOnday morning). I dont have more than 16 still it is not getting downloaded.
inboxitems= inbox.Items.Restrict("[Unread] = true"); /// This measn the email is not read which is true

if (newEmail.Attachments[i].FileName.Contains( "Logic")) // If Email attachment conatins name as LOgic only them it will download to my shared location 

Item ADD:I dont have more than 16 still it is not getting downloaded.

Comment: Try to check out the [MarkForDownload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866920(v=office.15).aspx) property of Outlook items - an [OlRemoteStatus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862994.aspx) value that determines the status of an item once it is received by a remote user.