# MArk for Download Property in outlook ( C#)

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

I am writing a plugin to download Email which has attachment .So Email comes Daily at 6 and gets downloaded  into a Folder,problem comes on Monday when I open my laptop I see 3 mails from Sat, Sun , Monday. And I see that  the Attachment  Downloaded  is only for Saturday’s. I saw that some one told me to use "Mark as Download" Property in outlook  to check whether it has downloaded or not and get latest attachment that is on  Monday. Can some please help me a syntax  or EXAMPLE in C# for Mark as downloaded property

Answer (score 0):

MailItem.MarkForDownload Boolean property. It is read/write.

Comment: can u share a C# example please?

Comment: MailItem.MarkForDownload  = true?

Comment: Ya if it is true that means Attachment has been downloaded ; If it is false the attachemnt has not been downloaded how to download that attachment?

Comment: It will be downloaded asynchronously late. What kind of store is this? IMAP4 or Exchange?

Comment: i AM USING MICROSOFT OUTLOOK

Comment: I understand that. Against what server? Exchange? PST with POP3/SMTP? IMAP4?

Comment: With POP3 all the messages are downloaded immediately. There is no partial download. MarkForDownload will do absolutely nothing. What is the problem that you are trying to solve? What makes you think there are no attachments? Did you check with OutlookSpy (click IMessage, go to the GetAttachmentTable tab)?

Comment: can you please give me your email so that i can mail u my code and explai n it?

Comment: Please post your code here: let everybody benefit from the discussion.

Comment: I have written descrption  pasted the code here . Sine it is a long code
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28943865/custom-outlook-plug-in-not-downloading-as-expected

Comment: Ok, but is still unclear what exactly does not work: does Restrict return unexpected results? Do you not get the expected attachments in the Attachments collection?

Comment: Ok , so I get a email with attachment  daily at 6: am ,throught out week.
on sat and sunday i dont open my laptop , when I open my laptop on MOnday I see 3 emails with attachment (on Sat, Sun and monday)and the attachments are not getting downloaded. Only the first email got into the inbox attachment gets downloaded. rest of the attachments  are not getting downloaded...
Let me know if u still have doubt :-)
Thanks for the help...

Comment: Is it possible the attachments are not downloaded because they were not present in the message to begin with? What makes you think the attachments are actually there?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the person who suggested to use the [MarkForDownload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866920(v=office.15).aspx) property of the MailItem class was me...

```
Sub DownloadItems()  
  Dim mpfInbox As Outlook.Folder  
  Dim obj As Object  
  Dim i As Integer 
  Set mpfInbox = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)  
 'Loop all items in the Inbox folder  
  For i = 1 To mpfInbox.Items.Count  
    Set obj = mpfInbox.Items.Item(i)  
    'Verify if the state of the item is olHeaderOnly  
    If obj.DownloadState = olHeaderOnly Then  
      MsgBox ("This item has not been fully downloaded.")  
      'Mark the item to be downloaded.  
      obj.MarkForDownload = olMarkedForDownload  
    End If  
  Next  
End Sub
```

Be aware, setting the property doesn't start downloading items. You need to initiate the synchronization process in the code or wait until Outlook starts recieving/checking for emails.

You can use the [Start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863925(v=office.15).aspx) method of the SyncObject class which begins synchronizing a user's folders using the specified Send\Receive group. For example:

```
Public Sub Sync() 
  Dim nsp As Outlook.NameSpace  
  Dim sycs As Outlook.SyncObjects 
  Dim syc As Outlook.SyncObject 
  Dim i As Integer  
  Dim strPrompt As Integer 
  Set nsp = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
  Set sycs = nsp.SyncObjects 
  For i = 1 To sycs.Count 
    Set syc = sycs.Item(i) 
    strPrompt = MsgBox("Do you wish to synchronize " & syc.Name &"?", vbYesNo) 
    If strPrompt = vbYes Then 
      syc.Start 
    End If 
  Next 
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Eugene Astafiev,

Can you please share Example in C# as I dont know the code what u have wrriten.

Comment: I have written code as 
if (inboxitems.DownloadState == Outlook.OlDownloadState.olFullItem)
                            {
 newEmail.MarkForDownload = olMarkedForDownload;
String Des= destinationDirectory.Remove(0, 1);
newEmail.Attachments[i].SaveAsFile(destinationDirectory +
 newEmail.Attachments[i].FileName);
Erro: Item is already downloaded But is not downloaed , when debugged it is stopping at  newEmail.MarkForDownload = olMarkedForDownload;

Comment: System.Runtime.InteropService.COM EXCEPTION:"This item is already Downloaded ; it cannot be marked for download".
I am not understanding why should we mark as download?  Can you please help me out.